# Sublime Text 3 - The autocomplete closes too soon, I can't even look at the list

Tags: javascript, html

I am programming HTML using Sublime Text 3 and every time autocomplete pops up, it stays up for not even a second and closes. I've tried putting the mouse inside the list and that doesn't work, even while I'm scrolling through the list it'll close. Does anyone know the fix for this? I've been searching and can't find anything.

Comment: Do you use in Macbook or Window?

Comment: use ctrl+space to open again. auto completion hints don't automatically disappear - probably you have a plugin installed that is hiding them? just set the save_on_focus_lost preference to true in your User preferences. Also ask such question in superuser community.